# angular-jasmine: testing component that draws dom using timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following functionality in my custom directive:

```
link: function (scope, element) {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.inline(element.find('div[contenteditable]')[0], {}
```

I want to test that the directive is linked and the editor is created under `element` using `CKEDITOR.inline` method. So I have this test:

```
it('should compile', function () {  

    var element = angular.element('<directive></directive>');
    var compiled = $compile(element)(scope);
    $('body').append(compiled);

    expect(element.find('.ckeditor')).toExist();
});
```

The problem is that `CKEDITOR` updates DOM asynchronously:

```
CKEDITOR.inline = function(element) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        element.append('<div class=ckeditor></div>');
    },0);
}
```

So my test fails to find the element with the class because it's executed synchronously, while the element is added inside `inline` method *after* the test because of `setTimeout`. How do I test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specs can become [asynchronous](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support):

```
it('should compile', function (done) {  
    ...
    setTimeout(() => {
        expect(element.find('.ckeditor')).toExist();
        done();
    }, 10);
});
```

Or better, [`jasmine.clock`](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) can be used:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.clock().install();
});

afterEach(function() {
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
});


it('should compile', function () {  
    ...
    jasmine.clock().tick(10);
    expect(element.find('.ckeditor')).toExist();
});
```